# Extjs - Paging Toolbar: Paging doesn't keep the previous request (store.load) using Server proxy

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

Extjs 4.2.2

I have a store with an ajax proxy that I don't autoload. It's attached to a grid and the grid has a paging toolbar.

I allow the user to choose some options in a form then I call `store.load( { params:{some params} } );`. I get the results back correctly from the server.

If the user uses the paging toolbar a new request is made, without the params that were used to make the previous request.

Is there a way to make the store load data as expected?

I know I could manually set the extraParams on the proxy and then call `store.load()` with no params. And then when Paging Toolbar makes a request it will use those extraParams.

I have also overridden store.loadPage() to rebuild the request/params, and set the correct start size.

What's the correct way to do this? To me the expected functionality is if I've changed the query and I want the next page of those results, I should get the next page of those results. Not get the next page of some other query/result.

Example store:

```
Ext.create( 'Ext.data.Store',{
   storeId:'some id',
   model:'some model',
   autoLoad:false,
   proxy:{
       type:'ajax',
       url:'some url',
       //extraParams: {sticky params},
       limitParam:'rows',
       pageParam:undefined,
       startParam:'start'
   },

    loadPage:function( page, options ){
        //Build the current query
        var o = /*biuld params object*/;

        //Update the page size
        o.start = (page - 1) * this.pageSize;

        if( options ){
            options.params = o;
        }else{
            options = {
                params:o
            };
        }
        //Pass it along to the parent loadPage.
        this.callParent( [page, options] );
    }
});
```

---

Actually I guess I was wrong, I can't just set extraParams manually and have the paging work.
They use Ext.applyif, which doesn't overwrite properties if they are already exist. So from the source

ext-all-debug.js
buildRequest: function(operation) {
        var me = this,

```
        params = operation.params = Ext.apply({}, operation.params, me.extraParams),
        request;


    Ext.applyIf(params, me.getParams(operation));




    if (operation.id !== undefined && params[me.idParam] === undefined) {
        params[me.idParam] = operation.id;
    }
    ...
```

This gets the paging information.
    me.getParams(operation)
And my params object has the paging information on it. So I guess what I have to do is not set the initial paging information myself, and let Ext handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I can't set the initial paging information manually. I would have to use the store to set the page.